# How to make scrapy retry an URL if it gets 307 in response code?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am trying to scrape https://zillow.com using proxies. But for the most of the URLs, I am getting redirected to a captcha verification page. For example,

I want to fetch: https://www.zillow.com/homes/90001_rb/

But I am getting redirected to https://www.zillow.com/captchaPerimeterX/?url=%2fhomes%2f90001_rb%2f2_p%2f&uuid=6da17b30-59a7-11e8-861d-5999f3314703&vid=

Hence, I want the scraper to retry those URLs for which it receives HTTP response code 307. I have tried adding the below code in settings.py.

```
RETRY_HTTP_CODES = [500, 503, 504, 400, 408, 307, 403]
RETRY_TIMES=5  
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 500,
'real_estate.middlewares.RealEstateDownloaderMiddleware':100,
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
}
```

But it did not work. I don't know what I am doing wrong. So if anyone can teach me how to do it in a proper way that would be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to add the following list also:

```
handle_httpstatus_list = [500, 503, 504, 400, 408, 307, 403]
```

So that scrapy can handle those Http codes first.

Comment: @ArindamGhosh Glad it did!